# loop not displaying posts on custom template page

Tags: posts, loop, templates

I have a site using a static homepage, and a posts page called Press(`press.php`).
The template is being pulled up correctly, however no posts are shown. 
Any ideas why? Thanks in advance.

[Live site.](http://parlourdc.com/press)

**press.php**

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Press
*/
?>


<?php get_header(); ?>

<div id="logo">
    <a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/parlour_side.png" alt="Parlour Salon logo" id="logo" /></a>
</div><!-- end logo -->

<div id="main">
    <div class="content">
        <?php if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
            <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
            <?php the_content('read more...'); ?>
            <p><?php the_date(); ?></p>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php else : ?>
                <p>I'm not sure what you're looking for.</p>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div><!-- end content -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a copy of `press.php` and rename it to `home.php`.

The page you selected **"Press"** to be the designated page for your posts in the dashboard under,

**Settings > Reading > Posts Page:** `[Press]`

...now falls under the control of the template hierarchy as listed by Milo.

First WordPress will look for the existence of `home.php` and if it exists, that will be applied as the template for your **Press** page.

If it does not exist, it will then move onto the default `index.php` and do the same.

Effectively your `press.php` is useless with regards to your **Press** page while it remains set under your **Settings > Reading** preferences.

Usually when creating custom themes my `index.php` looks something similar to,

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php 

    if(is_home() ) {

    include 'homepage.php';

    } else {

    //do as you wish here... i.e. display normal loop etc

   } 

?>

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

`homepage.php` for example would be your custom home page, as a result you don't need to use any of the settings in reading. This is only a very simplistic overview of something that can be done a number of ways, but just trying to give you an idea.

However for now, what you want is to be using `home.php` as described above.

Answer (score 1):

When you designate a page to be the page for posts, it's no longer a "page" in the conventional sense, and will not use the template assigned to it.

Check the [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy) to see how WordPress selects a template for this page:

> Home Page display
>
> **home.php**
>
> **index.php**

Comment: I've been told not to use index.php for this purpose? Or was that incorrect direction?

Comment: index.php is the fallback template for every content type, so if you want it specific to this page it's probably best to use home.php. [this image](http://codex.wordpress.org/images/1/18/Template_Hierarchy.png) shows the template loader flow, notice they all resolve to index.php if a more specific template is not found.

Comment: So, if I change `press.php` to `home.php` and remove the Template Name, the reassign settings in WP admin the loop will work?

Comment: yes, that's correct

Comment: Ok, thanks. When I'm in WP admin (Settings > Reading) I have Static Home Page selected, then Front Page=Home, what do I select for Posts Page?

Comment: Also, what template to assign to Press page in the Pages section of WP admin?